# Redis punsubscribe not unsubscribing

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have one redis client for pub-sub. I'm using a websocket message handler to dynamically subscribe to a redis channel. The payload of the websocket message contains an ID that I use to create the channel-name. So for example `lobby:${lobbyID}:joined`.
Subscribing to this channel works fine, messages are received when publishing to that channel.

But the issue that I'm having is that I want to unsubscribe from this channel at one point. My assumption by reading the redis-documentation is that I would use `punsubscribe` so I can unsubscribe from any channels with the pattern `lobby:*:joined`, but messages are still received after trying that.

```
import redis from 'redis';

const subClient = redis.createClient();

subClient.on('message', (channel, message) => {
  // Received message x on channel y
});

const socketHandlerSubscribe = (lobbyID) => {
  subClient.subscribe(`lobby:${lobbyID}:joined`);
}

const socketHandlerUnsubscribe = () => {
  subClient.punsubscribe('lobby:*:joined'); // true
}
```

When using the `redis-cli` the pattern seems valid when using `PUBSUB CHANNEL lobby:*:joined`. I could solve this issue by passing a lobby ID to the unsubscribe handler aswell, but `punsubscribe` *should* be the solution for it.

I also encountered this earlier with a scenario where I looped through an array of user ID's and created a subscription for each on `statuses:${userID}` and tried a `punsubscribe` on `statuses:*`, without any success.

Am I doing something wrong or this is an issue node-redis related? I'm using redis version `2.8.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that there are two different types of subscriptions. On channels and patterns. In my question I was subscribing to a channel, and unsubscribing on a pattern, these two are not 'compatible' so this won't work.
I used `nc` to debug this, as `redis-cli` won't allow additional commands when entering subscribed state.